# Let $f:[-1,\infty]\to R$,$f(x)=(x+1)^2-1$.Then the solution set of the equation $f^{-1}(x)=x$ is $\left\{-1,0\right\}$

Tags: functions

Let $f:[-1,\infty]\to R$,$f(x)=(x+1)^2-1$.Then the solution set of the equation $f^{-1}(x)=x$ is $\left\{-1,0\right\}$.Is this statement true of false?

---

$f(x)=(x+1)^2-1\Rightarrow f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x+1}-1$
Now solving $f^{-1}(x)=x$,we get
$\sqrt{x+1}-1=x$
$\sqrt{x+1}=x+1$
$x=0,-1$
It appears that this statement is true but my book says this statement is false.I dont know where i am wrong.Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  $f$ is defined from  $[-1, \infty]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then your $f$ is not bijective ( indeed  $f$ is not surjective as  $-2$ as no preimage by $f$). 
Then $f^{-1}$ is not  defined, so how to solve the equation  $f^{-1}(x)=x$ ?

However, if you restrict your $f$ so that  $f:[-1, \infty] \rightarrow [-1,\infty] $, then in this case, your fucntion is bijective, and 
 $f^{-1} : [-1, \infty] \rightarrow [-1,\infty]$  is uniquely defined by $ f^{-1}(x)= \sqrt{x+1}-1$. In this case  the equation  $f^{-1}(x)=x$ has only two solutions  $0$ and  $-1$.

Comment: I forgot to test this function for bijectivity.Thanks@Nizar